# How to connect multiple database in phalcon framework

Tags: phalcon, phalconeye

i have to database namely master and xyz ,in that i required to connect both database in application .
so is it possible to connect multiple database in one application and yes then how.?

Answer (score 14):

Set your connections in DI:

```
//This service returns a MySQL database
$di->set('dbMaster', function() {
     return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
        "host" => "localhost",
        "username" => "",
        "password" => "",
        "dbname" => ""
    ));
});

//This service returns a PostgreSQL database
$di->set('dbSlave', function() {
     return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
        "host" => "localhost",
        "username" => "",
        "password" => "",
        "dbname" => ""
    ));
});
```

In your models choose the connection:

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->setConnectionService('dbMaster');
    //or
    $this->setConnectionService('dbSlave');
}
```

Comment: but using this coding  i can  use only one database at time in model but i want to use both database in same model

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not sure what you try to achieve. Probably you have your reasons, but as an advice, you should try to keep the model, for one connection and one table. If you can explain better what is your goal, maybe I or someone else can help you with the right solution.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do this, using the same configuration

```
//This service returns a MySQL database
$di->set('dbMaster', function() {
    return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
        "host" => "localhost",
        "username" => "",
        "password" => "",
        "dbname" => ""
    ));
});

//This service returns a PostgreSQL database
$di->set('dbSlave', function() {
    return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql(array(
         "host" => "localhost",
         "username" => "",
         "password" => "",
         "dbname" => ""
    ));
});
```

In your model set

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->setReadConnectionService('dbSlave');
    $this->setWriteConnectionService('dbMaster');

    $this->setSource('table_name');
}
```

If you use transaction, remember in the injector dependency to change

```
$di->set('dbMaster' ....
```

For

```
$di->setShared('dbMaster'....
```

And the rest is the same